# What is the runtime and space complexity of this algorithm and why

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o

In practising some algorithms I came across the below problem, I'm having trouble figuring out what the time and space complexity is.

**Problem:**
Print pairs of nums from array that add up to the sum of k.
Eg

```
int[] arr =  new int[]{1, 7, 2, 3, 4};
int k = 4;
findSum(arr, k);
```

will output

```
Pair: 1, 3
```

**My Question:**
What is the runtime and space complexity of the solution below?

**Java example below:**

```
private void findSum(int[] arr, int k) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length < 2)
        throw new RuntimeException();

    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int i = 0; int j = arr.length -1;
    while (i < j) {
        int sum = arr[i] + arr[j];
        if (sum == k)
        {
            System.out.println("Pair: " + arr[i] + ", " + arr[j]);
            i++;
        } else if (sum > k) {
            j--;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on what the complexity of `sort()` is. Can we assume a decent, `O(n log n)` implementation? (Or does Java use bogosort? :P)

Comment: assume a complexity of O(n log n) for sort

Answer (score 8):

Since you are sorting the array first, that takes O(n log n) -- n is size of the array

But the while loop takes at most O(n). Therefore, in total: O(n log n + n) = O(n log n).

Regarding space complexity, the array takes O(n) + 2 constant variables which is still O(n).

Note: Java's Arrays.sort uses [modified mergesort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) -- O(n log n).

Comment: `O(n log n) + O(n)` is not quite `O(n)`.

Comment: Does the while loop only take O(n) even though it might visit some values more than once?

Comment: "Since you are sorting the array first, that takes O(n)..." Typo there.

Comment: the loop iterates n times, correct? but each time it would access two elements, therefore 2*n accesses which is still O(n).

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo :)

Comment: Quite old answer, but could you maybe explay why O(n log n + n) = O(n log n)?

Comment: Big O shows complexity class.. and since O(n log n) is superset of O(n) (or O(n log n) is dominant), therefore we can simply ignore the weaker party which here is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Let n be the size of the array:

Space complexity: O(n) - an array of length n + few variables. 
Time complexity: O(n logn) - sorting takes O(n logn) and the while loop will make exactly n iterations. To proof this consider the value of j-i. It starts at beginning from n-1, and after every iteration it decreases by one. The loop stops when i=j, so in other words when j-i=0.